# Evaluate the line integral of the given vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric, line-integrals

The formula I'm using is $\int_C \mathbf F \bullet d\mathbf r$

The given vector field is
$$F(x,y) = \frac{x}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}}\vec i +\frac{y}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}} \vec j$$
and the curve C given parametrically by
$$r(t)=e^{2t}\cos(3t)\vec i + e^{2t}\sin(3t)\vec j,\space 0\leq t\leq 2\pi$$
$$r^{'}(t)= -3e^{2t}\sin(3t)+2e^{2t}\cos(3t)\vec i + 2e^{2t}\sin(3t)+3e^{2t}\cos(3t)\vec j$$

The integral will then be
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\left<\frac{e^{2t}\cos(3t)}{(e^{2t}\cos(3t))^2 + (e^{2t}\sin(3t))^2)^{3/2}}+ \frac{e^{2t}\sin(3t)}{(e^{2t}\cos(3t))^2 + (e^{2t}\sin(3t))^2)^{3/2}}\right> \bullet \left<-3e^{2t}\sin(3t)+2e^{2t}\cos(3t), \space2e^{2t}\sin(3t)+3e^{2t}\cos(3t)\right>dt$$
After working that whole thing out I got
$$\int_0^{2π} \frac{2}{e^{2t}}dt=1-\frac{1}{e^{4\pi}}$$
Am I correct?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Basically I wanna know if I my answer is correct because of the massive amount of arithmetic I'm not sure if I messed up somewhere along the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your working is correct. However I am not sure if you are aware that for conservative vector field, there is a much easier way for you to get to the answer. The line integral will only depend on the end points and not on the chosen path. Here is details for this problem -

$F(x,y) = \frac{x}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}}\vec i +\frac{y}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}} \vec j$ is a conservative vector field.

Please note the potential function for the vector field is

$f(x,y) = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} + c \,$ where $c$ is a constant.

Just to confirm, you can see  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}i + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}j \,$ is your vector field.

So $\int_C \vec{F}  \cdot{d\vec{r}} = \int_C \nabla {f} \cdot {d\vec{r}} = f(\vec{r}(2\pi)) - f(\vec{r}(0))$.

Now $\vec{r}(0) = (1, 0) \,$ and $\vec{r}(2\pi) = (e^{4\pi}, 0) \,$

So our line integral is simply $ = f(e^{4\pi}, 0) - f(1,0) = \displaystyle 1 - \frac{1}{e^{4\pi}}$.

Answer (score 1):

$F(x,y)$ is a scalar valued function.

We don't use an inner product, we use the magnitude of $dr$

$\int F(x(t),y(t))\|r'(t)\|\ dt$

$r'(t) = e^{2t} \langle 2\cos 3t - 3\sin 3t, 2\sin 3t + 3\cos 3t\rangle$

$\|r'(t)\| = \sqrt{2^2 + 3^2} e^{2t}$

$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac {e^{2t}(\sin t + \cos t)}{e^{3t}} e^{2t}\sqrt 13 \ dt\\
\sqrt {13} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{t}(\sin t + \cos t) \ dt\\
\sqrt {13} (\frac {e^t(\cos 3t + 3\sin 3t)}{10} + \frac {e^t(\sin 3t - 3\cos 3t)}{10})|_0^{2\pi}\\
\frac {\sqrt {13}\ e^t}{10}(4\sin t - 2\cos t)|_0^{2\pi}\\
\frac {\sqrt {13} (1-e^{2\pi})}{5}\\
$

Comment: I appreciate all the work you've done but I believe you misunderstood the question due to an error made by me. $\mathbf F (x,y)$ is a vector field, I forgot to add the vector indexes.